# Disable archives page for custom post type

Tags: wordpress

**QUESTION**: How to remove or disable custom post type's archive page?

I have created survey plugin, the survey questions will be a custom post type. How can I make the archives page for my CPT be disabled?

**For instance**, when I edit the URL:

> `http://localhost/wordpress/survey/surveyquestion1` to
>
> `http://localhost/wordpress/survey`

it displays all the questions which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solve my problem myself. I found discussions on [Wordpress development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). This one works [Removed custom post type archive page shows blog page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218689/removed-custom-post-type-archive-page-shows-blog-page).

> Upon creating the add_action hook that will register the custom post type on the `labels` part, include  `'has_archive' => false,` this will disable the archives page for the custom post type.